# How to post data from my html page to a listener?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm currently designing a UI for an Automated Parking System. I currently need to test if my page sends out data from a form by sending it to a listener. I currently have this code but I'm not sure why it isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is my code that sends the data to a local listener.

```
<script>
        var INPARK = {cardID: $("#ticket_num").val(), lift: 1, floor: 1};
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url: '192.168.150.148:5007',
          contentType:"application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify(INPARK)
        });
      </script>
```

This is the listener code.

```
var HOST = '192.168.150.148'; // This should be your IP of 192.168.150.XXX
var PORT = 5007;

var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    // Only listen for POST requests
    if (req.method === 'POST') {

        var buffer = '';

        req.on('data', function (chunk) {
            buffer += chunk;
        });

        req.on('end', function () {

            var path = req.url.substring(0, req.url.indexOf('/', 1)).toUpperCase();
            var json;

            try {
                json = JSON.parse(buffer);
            } catch (err) {
                //
            }

            if (path === '/INPARK') {

                // Handle INPARK request
                console.log(json);

                res.write('inpark results');

            } else if (path === '/OUTPARK') {

                // Handle OUTPARK request
                console.log(json);

                res.write('outpark results');

            } else {

                // Do nothing - Bad request

                res.write('BAD REQUEST');
            }

            // Close the connection
            res.end(); 
        });
    }

}).listen(PORT, HOST, function () {
    console.log('Listening at %s:%s', HOST, PORT);
});
```

Comment: If you really want to use Node for anything like this... I highly recommend using the Express framework

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What error message are you getting? What is the expected output? Please provide more info on what went wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: The expected output is this

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request is most likely going from port 80 or 443 to 5007, which is a cross domain request, hence it will fail,

If you want to resolve this issue, read up on CORS:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing,

and JSONP: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP